# using AlertDialog in Message Handler

Tags: android, xmpp, handler, android-alertdialog, asmack

I'm working on a Xmpp chat application.

In my PacketListener I'm trying to handle subscription request, It's all working like a charm except AlertDialog. It doesn't show up, so I can't get confirmation from user.

I've tried ,

- `Toast.makeText()`
- Changing UI(TextView)
- `getApplicationContext()` instead of `Display.this`

But none of them work.

As I said, I'm not getting any error, I tried to debug also, It seems working on code side.

Here is my code,

```
//imports....
public class Display extends Activity {
  //....more codes

    private void addListener() {

        //subscribe request handler
        Roster roster = conn.getRoster();
        roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
        PacketListener packetListener = new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {}
        };

        conn.addPacketListener(packetListener, new PacketFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Presence presence = (Presence)packet;
            subscriptonAnswer = false;
            if(packet instanceof Presence) {
                if(((Presence)packet).getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribe))  {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Display.this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("Subscription Message")
                        .setMessage(StringUtils.parseName(packet.getFrom())+ " wants to add you, do you accept?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             Presence reply = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                             reply.setTo(presence.getFrom());
                             conn.sendPacket(reply);
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }});

    }

//....more codes
}
```

Comment: I would think you need to be on a UI thread to use UI widgets. I haven't used Android myself but this is typically the case with java GUI frameworks.  In addition to that, you are blocking the reader thread with user interaction, which IMHO is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Robin, your comment was very helpful to figure out my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the second time I have encountered same problem, but the first one had a different structure so at the first time I couldn't figure out it.

But [@Robin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420202/using-alertdialog-in-message-handler#comment20112554_14420202) disabused me of problem.

As he said I have to be on UI thread to use UI widgets, to solve this problem I used [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
  private Handler handler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          //I'm free to manage UI Widgets here
      }
  };

  //......
  // I have to just sendmessage here
  if(packet instanceof Presence) {
      if(((Presence)packet).getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribe))  {
          handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
      }
  }
  //......
```